# Grid backgrounded text with fixed width font looks different on different devices

Tags: javascript, css

What I want to achieve is a grid backgrounded long text where every letter fits in the middle of each square (see screenshot below). I'm using a contenteditable div with a grid background and I'm using fixed width font: `font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace`.
The square size, the letter-spacing, the font-size, margin, padding are all set as a fixed px, but for some reason text looks different on different browsers / OS.

For example under Linux on Firefox it looks like this:
[image: letters fit within square in Firefox under Linux]

While on Chrome (Linux) letters don't fit within squares:
[image: letters don't fit within square in Chrome under Linux]

I also tried it on Chrome under a tablet running Windows and it looks like the same as the one on my Firefox. So it seems like it not just between browsers, but even operating systems.

What would be the best way to achieve the same look on all browsers / devices?

Comment: Could you post some code or a JSFiddle please?

Comment: Here's the piece of code I'm using: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/wvwp77bb/1/)
(For some reason it doesn't work on JSFiddle, but works on my PC).